# Strange error in java, symbol 'super.' not found

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've recently been working on a quick little space invaders game in java, and I came across a little bit of a problem because the 'aliens' weren't moving correctly. i found out through a quick google search that I just had to add a constructor and override it, however I came across an interesting error message when i did:

error: cannot find symbol: super.cpuMove(m);

```
                        ^(this points directly to the "." in the original error message)
```

I did end up figuring out a way to completely avoid this error by changing the code, but that change added about 50 - 60 unnecessary lines that I would very much like to convert back down to just a few quick lines. Here's the section of my code that this error occurred:

```
@Override
protected void cpuMove(ShapesMove m){
    super.cpuMove(m);
    cpu_x(m);
    cpu_y(m);
}
```

Why does this error message show up every time, no matter what I change about the rest of the code? And furthermore, why does it point to the "." instead of "super" or "cpuMove(m)"? I want to be able to fit this in, but it seems Java won't let me.

edit:

Here is the rest of my code. I thought that maybe it was something else and I wouldn't have to post this, so I apologize for that:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ShapesMove extends JPanel{

    public static int x = 40;
    public static int y = 40;
    public static int h = 240;
    public static int k = 240;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movement of 2d Shapes");
        final ShapesMove m = new ShapesMove();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(m);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Action actionRight = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionRightEvent){
                x += 10;
                m.repaint();
            }
        };

        Action actionLeft = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionLeftEvent){
                x -= 10;
                m.repaint();
            }
        };

        Action actionUp = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionUpEvent){
                y -= 10;
                m.repaint();
            }
        };

        Action actionDown = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionDownEvent){
                y += 10;
                m.repaint();
            }
        };

        KeyStroke right = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
        KeyStroke left = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");
        KeyStroke up = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP");
        KeyStroke down = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN");

        InputMap inputMap = m.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(right, "RIGHT");
        inputMap.put(left, "LEFT");
        inputMap.put(up, "UP");
        inputMap.put(down, "DOWN");
        m.getActionMap().put("RIGHT", actionRight);
        m.getActionMap().put("LEFT", actionLeft);
        m.getActionMap().put("UP", actionUp);
        m.getActionMap().put("DOWN", actionDown);

    }

    @Override
    protected void cpuMove(ShapesMove m){
        super.cpuMove(ShapesMove m);
        cpu_x(m);
        cpu_y(m);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void cpu_x(ShapesMove m){
        if(h > x){
            h -= 10;
            m.repaint();
        }else if(h < x){
            h += 10;
            m.repaint();
        }else{
            m.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void cpu_y(ShapesMove m){
        if(k > y){
            k -= 10;
            m.repaint();
        }else if(k < y){
            k += 10;
            m.repaint();
        }else{
            m.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(x, y, 40, 40);
        g.drawRect(h, k, 40, 40);
    }

}
```

a couple quick notes about the code: first off, I know I said this was a space invaders game and that right now this really only bears minimal to no resemblance of that, it's a WIP. I'm making my own images and animated background in photoshop, so that's why I have a rectangle and circle drawn instead of calling images. what this is really meant to do is simulate how an enemy in the game would "follow" the player when a method was called, because I wanted this game to have a few "Galaga" aspects as well.

Comment: What does the `cpuMove` method look like in the parent class?

Comment: Without seeing more code(your class and its super class), we can't say much about the *super* error.

Comment: Please share code of parent class .

Comment: Is this method implementing a method specified in an interface rather than in a superclass? If so, then there is no `super.cpuMove` method to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation is that you have misused "super" here.  "super" is used to refer to the parent class of a subclass.  If your class isn't extending anything, there is nothing there for it to reference or your super class does not have a "cpuMove" method and this is why you are getting an error.

Comment: So if `ShapesMove` is my main class, how do i fix this?

Comment: The method you have posted here for us, what class is it inside of?  Its super class would need a cpuMove method

Answer (score 0):

As message says,

your super class don't has method cpuMove(), matching `cpuMove(ShapesMove  m)` signature.